# Select the First value Greater than a specific value

Tags: sql

I have two tables first table is Stock Receiving

```
  Store   Item_No        Receiving_Time

   2       1         2020-05-27 13:44:27.829 UTC
   2       1         2020-05-27 17:44:28.829 UTC
   2       1         2020-05-28 14:44:28.829 UTC
   2       1         2020-05-29 14:44:28.829 UTC
```

Second one is item going Out of Stock

```
   Store   Item_No        Out_OF_Stock_Time

       2       1         2020-05-26 13:44:27.829 UTC
       2       1         2020-05-27 18:44:28.829 UTC
       2       1         2020-05-27 20:44:28.829 UTC
```

So i want to find the value when the last out of stock was filled in my case last out of stock happens on `2020-05-27 20:44:28.829 UTC` so output value should be `2020-05-28 14:44:28.829 UTC` 
from Stock Receiving Table

SO output:

```
Store Item_No.    Last_OutOfStock.              Received Time                   Difference Time
2.      1        2020-05-27 20:44:28.829 UTC    2020-05-28 14:44:28.829 UTC
```

My Query:

```
Select  o.store, o.item_No, Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time) as S, Min(r.Receiving_Time) as R
from Out_of_Stock o
join Stock_Receiving r on o.store = r.store and o.item_no = r.item_no
and S < R
group By o.store, o.item_No;
```

So it's not getting me the right result.

Comment: What database do you use ? What is the Difference  in your SO output ?

Comment: Hi @BadCoder, did any of the answers helped you? Was any of them correct ? Do you think other people's help deserve at least your small feedback in shape of some comment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query, if your Receiving_Time and Out_OF_Stock_Time is in date datatype, below query will work. If not please convert the format in the query

```
Select  o.store, o.item_No, Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time) as S, 
Min(r.Receiving_Time) as R, 
Min(r.Receiving_Time) - Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time) as Difference
from Out_of_Stock o
join Stock_Receiving r on o.store = r.store and o.item_no = r.item_no
group By o.store, o.item_No
having Min(r.Receiving_Time) > Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time);
```

Comment: `Min(r.Receiving_Time)` is always  greater than ` Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time)` how this will be ensured ?

Comment: You can use having clause, edited the query, please use it

Comment: Hi @JimMacaulay please can you tell me what have I unserstood wrong here ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11111d5bf8ece2bafdee18ff6803903b In this link you can see that this does not retrurn the correct results in Oracle. How can I test this answer to see it as correct ? OP (BadCoder) provided desired result in his question and I can not get them with this accepted answer . Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi @BadCoder, next to the comment above I would like to add that even the second answer that is not accepted here is providing the good results as does my answer... : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9af444df8b6b657c3df5b178b5cb2afc

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports you can use OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (
        Select  o.store, o.item_No, Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time) as s
        from Out_of_Stock o
        group by o.store, o.item_No
    ) xo
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT Min(Receiving_Time) Receiving_Time FROM Stock_Receiving r 
        WHERE xo.store = r.store and xo.item_no = r.item_no and r.Receiving_Time > xo.S) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle you can do it like this:

```
with cte as(select o.store
                   , o.item_No
                   , Max(o.Out_OF_Stock_Time) as S
            from Out_of_Stock o
            group By o.store, o.item_No)
select distinct cte.store
       , cte.item_No
       , cte.S "Last_OutOfStock"
       , first_value(r.Receiving_Time) over (order by r.Receiving_Time asc) "Received Time"
from cte
join Stock_Receiving r on cte.store = r.store and cte.item_no = r.item_no
where r.Receiving_Time > cte.S;
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e91e3bbf63a2eafa5ef9aa84a81a2e9)